# CFNetwork still passing CFStreamErrors even though its deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, core-foundation, deprecated, cfnetwork

I'm writing some code that is wrapping up some `CFNetwork` stuff to do DNS resolution in Objective-C.

Everything is fine and it's working, but I have a few questions:

The callback function prototype for `CFHost`'s asynchronous resolution is passing references to `CFStreamError` structures even though the documentation says `CFStreamError` is deprecated and `CFReadStreamCopyError` should be used instead, which will return a `CFError` struct.

The callback function is declared as such:

```
typedef void (CFHostClientCallBack) (
    CFHostRef theHost,
    CFHostInfoType typeInfo,
    const CFStreamError *error,
    void *info);
```

There doesn't seem to be any alternative to this callback that uses non-deprecated APIs.

I thought the point of deprecating API's was that new ones were introduced that supersede the older ones? If this is true, why isn't there an alternative callback to this one that makes use of the `CFReadStreamCopyError` function?

The main problem I'm having that `CFStreamErrors` are really nondescript... Is there anything I can do to turn a `CFStreamError` into a `CFError`?

---

Just to clarify a few points:

I don't believe I've misread the documentation on this point. the callback method used in CFHosts asynchronous resolution system passes in a `CFStreamError`. While `CFStreamError` itself may not be deprecated, the functions that return them, namely `CFReadStreamGetError` and `CFWriteStreamGetError` are deprecated. The documentation suggests using `CFReadStreamCopyError` and `CFWriteStreamCopyError` which return `CFError` instead of `CFStreamError`.

I am wrapping this code in Objective-C and I'm making a lot of use of Foundation objects. as such, `CFError` is a lot more useful to me than `CFStreamError` is because it's toll-free bridged with `NSError` and `CFStreamErrors` don't contain nearly as much useful information as a `CFError` does. Further, I'm not even dealing with a `CFStream` directly, so why should I have to deal with its specific error struct? Finally, I want to ultimately return an `NSError` in a delegate call back in my wrapper class.

Also, I know that deprecation doesn't instantly mean the method is gone, but if something is marked as deprecated, it would make sense (to me at least) to provide an alternative. Otherwise, the deprecated method/function/class etc, is still being used and there's no point in deprecating it until something supersedes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CFStreamError` struct is not actually deprecated. From the documentation, it looks like it will be in the next release (since they're deprecating methods that return it). For now, however, it looks like you will still have to deal with the struct itself, as no replacement callback has been made.

I realize this isn't the type of answer you were looking for, but the `CFStreamError` really hasn't been fully deprecated yet, so you won't have replacements for all uses of it.

Comment: Ok, well in that case, there doesn't seem to be much I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means it is *planned* to become obsolete. This is meant for Apple's software engineers as well as third-party software developers.

Also, you are misreading the documentation. The struct is returned by the *function* [CFReadStreamGetError](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamGetError). The documentation is suggesting new API functions to use, not a new error struct to use.

Comment: I didn't misread the docs. The wording in my question, however, is probably not the best. When I said that `CFReadStreamGetError` should be used instead of `CFStreamError`, I meant in general, instead of using `CFStreamError`s, one should use the structs returned by `CFReadStreamGetError`. But that's besides the point. The callback I'm using explicitly passes a `CFStreamError` and there is no `CFStream` for me to use `CFReadStreamGetError` on to get a non-deprecated error struct.